# Ajax response showing as single letters in datatable

Tags: arrays, ajax, datatables

I am trying to populate a table with data from mySQL table, I am trying to do this with ajax at present and I have it mostly working, the call works, the console log shows a correctly formated response

```
(3) ["management", "marketing", "profit"]
0: "management"
1: "marketing"
2: "profit"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

however the table looks like this 
I have searched for last few hours trying to solve this issue, but every time I make a step forward I seem to go three back.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'inc/sql/LoadWords.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success :  function(result){
      console.log(result);
      $('#word_data').dataTable( {
        data: result
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

All I want is for the table to show the words as full words not single letters.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

From documentation Datatables [Data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/index),

> The main data source used for a DataTable must always be an array (it
>   is created automatically when using DOM sourced data). Each item in
>   that array will define a row to be displayed

There are **three** basic Javascript data types as the data source for the rows, which are **array of:**

1. **Arrays - []** like [ [data1],[data2],... ]
2. **Objects - {}** like [ {data1},{data2},.. ]
3. **Instances** - new MyClass() like [new data(col1,col2),new data(col1,col2),..]

Now, you are missing parent brackets, which should **array of array**:

> **`[`** **[**'row1col1','row1col2'**]**, **[**'row2col1','row1co22'**]**,
>   **[**'row3col1','row3col2'**]**
>   **`]`**

You can refer an example of [Datatables Data Source Array](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array).

**Or below Example:**

```js
var result =[["management", "marketing", "profit"]];
$('document').ready(function(){
 
      $('#word_data').dataTable( {
        data: result
      });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="word_data" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```